# GigE Vision Cameras with C# libraries Open Source

Tags: c#, camera, gige-sdk

I'm currently using UVC compliants cameras, it's working fine with Visual Studio and AForge. 
As the cameras will be further away, i need to use Ethernet cameras and especially GigE Vision Cameras. I'm searching for an open source library working with Visual Studio...

I know that every camera comes with a SDK provided by the vendor. The problem is that i need to perform some image processing in order to do some object detection. That's why i really to extract the video stream so I can do basic filtering/transorfmations into VS2019.

Sincerely,
Alexis

Answer (score 0):

So far I know that is exactly the problem with these camera the drivers are all proprietary. That is the status from 2018. If something new came it should be in the years after that. In principle I think it is hard to develop a open-source library for commercial camera which do not comply to an open standard.